# PHP consuming too much RAM - Using Cronjobs

Tags: php, ubuntu, memory, server, cron

I have just set up a new server using Ubuntu 16.04 and php7-fpm. I've set up 3 cronjobs to run: every 5 minutes, every 7 minutes and every 10 minutes. All of the functions are PHP functions, that are connecting to a MySQL database + querying results from a 3rd party server. Looking at the results the cron jobs are always running from beginning to the end. So that can't be the issue - I believe.

So everything works perfectly, however, I can see that the RAM usage keeps increasing gradually and it's not stopping. I'm seeing that there are like 100+ PHP processes open on the server and each of them is using some of the virtual RAM. I guess this is because one PHP worker is being opened every time a CRON job starts.

Here are a few pictures: 
[image: 'Memory %']

[image: 'PHP Processes]

I can see that there are 4 PHP processes that are standing out from the others. Looks like that there is a lot of IO there also.

So I believe that something's not alright around there. The other strange thing is that I have more than 100+ PHP processes since yesterday -> which is logical since the cronjobs have run more than 100 times.

What is the issue here and how can I fix it? Is it possible that I have so many processes because I'm not returning anything at the end of the script? Or it must be something that's causing the script to overlap?

I'm using a Cloud Server with 2vCores, 4GB RAM, Ubuntu 16.04 OS, PHP7.0-fpm, Nginx.

Comment: I think, PHP does not end, maybe get into the infinite loop.

Comment: So every cron request , Spawn a new endless php processes

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Is it a problem if I'm not returning anything at the end of the script? As far as I know it should get into an endless loop.

Comment: you should set `set_time_limit(x secs)` to stop script to goes infinite . its a good case always to have.

Comment: cron starts a php process that runs your script till the end, then exits. So no, there should not be 100 php instances after 100 runs, as the php process should end at the end of the script. This means your scripts don't finish as they should. Returning something is not required for it to stop, it's just that the end of the script should be reached within reasonable time (definitely less time than the start interval). Can you post one of your scripts?

Comment: Just saw you wrote in a comment "As far as I know it should get into an endless loop". What do you mean by that? If your scripts have an infinite loop, that would definitely be the problem. Your scripts get restarted every 5/7/10 minutes, they should do one batch of work and then exit. There should be no infinite loop.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Thanks for your reply. Actually I mistyped that answer, I was trying to say: "As far as I know it should NOT get into an endless loop.". Is there anything that I can use to kill the script if it's running for too long? I've heard something about adding a number after the '* * * * *' in my crontab, but not entirely sure how to use it.

Comment: Using `set_time_limit()`, as suggested, could be used to set a limit. But that would not really solve the root problem, which is that the script(s) do not finish as they should. You should try to solve this first, and use `set_time_limit()` only for safety.